# Getting errors while using plist in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, plist

So I am using a plist file to store a NSMutableArray and when added an object also save it to that plist file. But I am getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:1];
_prsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"records.plist"];

prs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:_prsPath];

if (prs == nil) {
    prs = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

and after "addObject":

```
[prs writeToFile:_prsPath atomically:YES];
```

Struggeling with this code for hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, check if paths is nil, before trying to access any of its elements. Then, when trying to access its elements, check if the array contains enough elements (more than 0). Actually, you may skip step one as that will return 0 even if that array is nil.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't that be `NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];`?

The error you're getting is an out-of-bounds error. It means you're asking an array for an object at an index that is above it's highest index. In this case you're asking for an object at index 1 (2nd object) even though the highest index is 0 (only one object in the array).

Comment: Uh, changed 1 to 0 getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Btw, if array is likely to contain only one item, I prefer to use `[ar lastObject]` since it will silently return nil if there's no items at all.

Comment: it's going to contain as much items as the user adds.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? I don't see any other ``objectForIndex:` calls other then that.

Comment: uhh there are. This is the code I am using to add objects. http://pastie.org/private/byxjmf5k6rpsfcj4uz8qcw

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that method and see if those arrays have any objects in them. Probably not. So then you have to figure out why not. Is the prs array loaded properly? Does the plist file exist? What do you return in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: in numberOfRowsInSection: return [prs count]; - the array is loaded with:     prs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:_prsPath];

Comment: What about the detail array? Where do you load that?

Comment: that's not integrated with the plist yet. Just a normal NSMutableArray. Can that be the problem?

Comment: If it doesn't have any objects in it, when you try to load something from it, yes. Try this: `NSString *detailValue = [detail count] > indexPath.row ? [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] : nil;`.

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem. You should make sure that the details array is loaded with the main one properly. If you can't make that sure, you have to check before loading and set the `detailValue` to `nil` or `@""` to avoid an out-of-bounds error. That's what that line does, you have to replace your line with that.

Comment: Where do I need to put that one? (any possibility you can give some support via msn or sth? Think that's going to be alot faster. Appreciate it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `NSString *detailValue = [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. Does detailView have the same number of objects in it as prs? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: hmm, gonna check that out. - But where to put that code? in ViewDidLoad? (because indexPath.row may not be used there.)

Comment: Or can indexPath.row be used there?

Comment: Just deleted this section in my app. Just not worth it. thanks anyway.